# How to use multicamera function in Google Tango's delta camera in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Currently I want to use Tango delta camera and Tango AR camera. I enabled depth perception and video overlay in Tango Manager, in the Tango delta camera, I went to multicamera and added Tango AR Screen and disabled AR post processing.

However, I still can't see any video overlay. Is there anything that I can do to use the two cameras at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Google+ https://plus.google.com/115543030331782764133/posts/b1ZCVMtWHDg

After updating the new Tango Unity SDK, now I can use Tango Camera prefab and add AR script or Delta Camera script to it.